# Typescript transform a reducers type to actions

Tags: typescript

I have a object link this:

```
const reducers = {
  increment: (state: State, payload: number) => {
    return { count: state.count + payload };
  },
  decrement: (state: State, payload: number) => {
    return { count: state.count - payload };
  },
  console: (state: State, payload: string) => {
    console.log(payload);
    return { count: state.count };
  },
};
```

if I want get type like this:

```
type reducerType =
  | { type: 'increment'; payload: number }
  | { type: 'decrement'; payload: number }
  | { type: 'console'; payload: string };
```

How should I transform it just like `Exclud` or `Pick`?

Answer (score 2):

First lets extract type from your const with

```js
type Reducer = typeof reducers;
```

Then get type of payload

```js
type ExtractPayload<T> = T extends (arg1: any, payload: infer U) => any ? U : never;
```

Another tool which we will need is type for reducer

```js
type ToReducerType<K extends KeyT, T> = { "type": K, payload: T };
```

(forget about KeyT for now)
Now we have everything to define our type tho

```js
type ToReducersType<T> = { [P in keyof T]: ToReducerType<P, ExtractPayload<T[P]>> }[keyof T];
```

Should do what you want.

Here is whole example [tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20reducers%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20increment%3A%20(state%3A%20State%2C%20payload%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20count%3A%20state.count%20%2B%20payload%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20decrement%3A%20(state%3A%20State%2C%20payload%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20count%3A%20state.count%20-%20payload%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20console%3A%20(state%3A%20State%2C%20payload%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(payload)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20count%3A%20state.count%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20KeyT%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20symbol%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Reducer%20%3D%20typeof%20reducers%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ExtractPayload%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20(arg1%3A%20any%2C%20payload%3A%20infer%20U)%20%3D%3E%20any%20%3F%20U%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ToReducerType%3CK%20extends%20KeyT%2C%20T%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%22type%22%3A%20K%2C%20payload%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ToReducersType%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20ToReducerType%3CP%2C%20ExtractPayload%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3E%20%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ReducerTypes%20%3D%20ToReducersType%3CReducer%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20ReducerTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22decrement%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%3A%206%0D%0A%7D)